# Is it possible to do simple arithmetic in sed addresses?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

Is it possible to do simple arithmetic in sed addresses?
Judging by the ["addresses" manual section](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses), the answer seems no.  But maybe there is a workaround?

For example, how can I print the second last line of a file?  It would be cool something like:

```
sed -n '$-1 p' file
```

But it obviously does not work... so I usually have to do multiple sed calls, first for identifying the line, then do the arithmetic using the shell `$((expr))` and then finally call sed  again.  Like this:

```
sed -n "$(($(sed -n '$ =' file)-1)) p" file
```

Is there a "better", more compact, more readable way for doing arithmetics with sed addresses?

In a serious moment of procrastination, I decided to write a small [script that quickly changes the xterm colorscheme](https://bitbucket.org/mrucci/xterm-colorscheme.sh/src/tip/xterm-colorscheme.sh).  The idea is that you have the `.Xresources` a file with a start marker and an end marker:

```
...
START_MARKER
...
END_MARKER
...
```

and you want to delete everything that is between the markers, but not the markers themselves.  Again, it would be great to do something like:

```
sed '/START_MARKER/+1,/END_MARKER/-1 d' file
```

...but you can't!

Comment: Could you explain more about what you're trying to do? it doesn't sound like `sed` is the right tool for the job.

Comment: I added another example where it could be handy to do simple arithmetic with addresses,  and that's exactly the problem I was trying to solve.

Comment: `sed` operates on streams of input data and as such does not know when it is at the second last line. It can only detect the last line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, one can't directly do math in sed<sup>1</sup>, even addresses. But you can use some trickery to do what you want:

Second-last row:

```
$ seq 5 | sed -n -e '${ # On the last line
> g # Replace the buffer with the hold space
> p # and print it
> }
> h' # All lines, store the current line in the hold space.
4
```

Between `START` and `END`:

```
$ cat test.in
1
START
2
3
END
4
$ cat test.in | sed '/^START$/,/^END$/{
> /^START$/d
> /^END$/d
> p
> }
> d'
2
3
$ cat test.in | sed -n -e '/^START$/,/^END$/!d' -e '/^START/d' -e '/^END$/d' -e p
2
3
```

I'm using a BSD (mac) `sed`; on GNU systems you can use `;` between lines instead of a newline. Or stick it in a script.

1: Sed is Turing complete, so you can do math, but it's unwieldy at best: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/A%2BB#sed

<sub>Yes, I know, UUOC; it's for illustration only</sub>

Comment: So, the conclusion seems that there is no **general** way of dealing with arithmetic in addresses, just very specific workarounds.  Even your solution to the "second last line problem" does not generalize to the "third last line problem"...

Answer (score 1):

Delete the second last line:

```
sed ':r;$!{N;br};s/\n[^\n]*\(\n[^\n]*\)$/\1/' file
```

Delete everything inside markers:

```
sed ':r;$!{N;br};s/START_MARKER.*END_MARKER/START_MARKER\nEND_MARKER/' file
```

Far from being elegant, but kinda works.

As it was mentioned in the comments, `sed` operates on lines. However, you can read another line into the pattern space with `N` command. The two lines will now both be in the pattern space and will be separated with a `\n`. `sed` also has means of execution flow control, namely labels and conditional/unconditional branches. Everything is documented in `man sed`, also [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) is a full reference with examples. In the code above `r` is a label; `$!{..}` means "everywhere except last line, do `..`; `N;br` reads another line and branches unconditionally to `r` again. So with `:r;$!{N;br}` you read all the input into the pattern space and then you operate on it as a single line with `\n` separating lines of the input.

Comment: Could you please add a minimal explanation of what is happening in there :)?

Comment: And what `sed` version crosses newlines like that? None I've ever seen, nor the three I just tried explicitly (mac/BSD, GNU, busybox).

Comment: And `.` is explicitly defined as anything *but* a newline

Comment: @Kevin I'm not sure I understand what you mean by crossing newlines. The examples seem to work in my `GNU sed version 4.2.1`, and it does match newlines as `.`.

Comment: Very interesting trick.  Will definitively try to remember the _throw everything in pattern space command_ `:r;$!{N;br}`.  As you admitted, it does not look like the right tool for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed);

```
sed '$!N;$s/.*\n//;P;D' file
```

and this works and should be easy to understand:

```
sed '/start/,/end/!d;//d' file
```

These are solutions to your questions but as for arithmetic best use awk or perl.

Answer (score 0):

You have some good `sed` suggestions, here's one based on GNU `awk`:

```
awk -v RS='START_MARKER|END_MARKER' 'RT == "END_MARKER"' infile
```

- `RS='START_MARKER|END_MARKER'` splits input with the markers as separators.
- `RT` is set to the matched separator, when it matches "END" the default block `{print $0}` is executed.

So for example if you wanted to print all but the last three lines, set FS to `\n` and apply the appropriate loop:

```
awk -v RS='START_MARKER|END_MARKER' -v FS='\n' 'RT == "END" { for(i=1; i<NF-3; i++) print $i }' infile
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple method to show second last line of the file.

```
TOTAL_LENGTH=$(cat file_name | wc -l)
SECOND_LAST_LINE=`expr $TOTAL_LENGTH - 1`
head -$SECOND_LAST_LINE | tail -1
```

If you want to delete the second last line from the file:

```
sed -i "$SECOND_LAST_LINE"d file_name
```

Comment: ... or `cat file | tail -2 | head -1`.  The question is about address manipulation in sed.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: Useless use of cat.  Two demerits.

Answer (score -1):

A more comprehensive treatment for doing arithmetic in `sed`is given in solution #2. An introduction to using `sed` to `sed' its own script is here.

As the brain pain strain incurred in solution #2 from the quixotic comment demands of too much "hand waving" actually is too much "hand waving" of code, in juxtaposition, this is solution #3:

```
echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd\ne' | sed -n '1!G;h;$p' | sed -n 3p
```

which still uses piping ("But maybe there is a workaround?"), where the numeral 3 must be replaced "by hand" for the desired line from the end of the file ala `$-3`.

Suppose the `sed` script is  `'$-4 p;  $-6p;  $-8 p;'`

```
echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng\nh\ni'  | 
sed  -n '1!G;h;$p'                   | 
sed  -n '4 p; 6p; 8 p;'              | 
sed  -n '1!G;h;$p'
```

does the job via

```
echo  '$-4 p;  $-6p;  $-8 p;'  |   sed s/$-//
```

Caveats:
The `sed` commands must be as simple as `p`rint.
The "simple arithmetic" can only be of the form '$-n'.
The arithmetic is not calculated "normally".

A "single" 'sed' command string (a "line" if the previous piping is considered as such) would embed and combine these two commands as outlined in the next answer #2.

---

The coup de grâce.

Given the perfunctory dismissal of the first answer here is #2:

As this is only the 2nd or 3rd time writing a substantial `sed` script, serious syntax subtlety (s)circumvention scuppering solutions seemed sufficient: ala

```
# file prep 
echo -e '  a\n  b\n  c\n  d\n  e\n  f' >test
```

The following strikeout is not incorrect but after playing and "messing about" with `sed` [with an SO problem over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560734/count-total-number-of-pattern-between-two-pattern-using-sed-if-possible-in-lin/69774849#69774849) the `sed` `e`xecute can be simpler w/o IO redirection if run from the pattern buffer to get the file length line count `$` via:

```
sed  -e  '1{h; s/.*/sed -n  "$="  test  /e' -e 'p;x}; ${p;x;}' test
```

The `$=` enumeration is held in the hold buffer from the get go and printed again at the end.

```
# get "sed -n  $= test" command output into sed script
sed -n '1esed -n  "$=" test >sedr' test

# see where this is headed? so far "sed -n ... test" is irrelevant
# a pedantic "sed" only solution would keep it this way with
# all the required "sed"'ng as part of an 'e' command or '$e'
# where the 'sedr' file is itself "sed"'d ultimately to a final
# command 'sed -n /<the calculated line number>/p' 

# one could quibble whether '>sedr' io redirection is "pure sed" 

# modify 'sedr'with [the sed RPN][1] to get <the calculated line number>
```

```
# with judicious use of "sed"'s 'r' command and buffering will
# realize the effective script to compute the desired result

# this is left as an exercise needing perverse persistence with
# a certain amount of masochistic agony
```

As a hint as to how to proceed; using the technique of solution #3 the `sed` script `$-` addresses are now replaced by the `$=` value and `-`. So `sed` is again used to edit its own script.

Parsing the `sed` script must accurately modify *just* the `$-` in addresses only.

Also, to use the RPN calculator the infix arithmetic must have post fixed operators. It is a conventional paradigm in theories of automata and formal languages to convert Polish Notation or its Reverse to Infix and vice versa.

Hopefully, this establishes the answer in the afirmative that it can be done (mais, pas par moi) and in the negative that it is *not* a trivial exercice (c'est par moi).

Excruciating rationale for an *arbitrary* solution is at the end.

The environment used for the empirical tests:

```
linuxuser@ubuntu:~$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.4
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

linuxuser@ubuntu:~$  uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-74-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 19 08:06:00 UTC 2019 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

linuxuser@ubuntu:~$ lsbname -a
lsbname: command not found
linuxuser@ubuntu:~$ apropos lsb
lsb_release (1)      - print distribution-specific information
lsblk (8)            - list block devices
linuxuser@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

---

Solution #1

A technique thinking outside inside the box:

```
seq 60  |  sed -n '$!p'  |  sed -n '$!p'  |  sed -n '$!p' |  sed -n '$p'
```

which prints:

```
57
```

specifically, for the second last line:

```
sed -n '$!p' file  |  sed -n '$p'
```

More generally, a script can iterate over `sed -n '$!p'` to "count backwards" from the end of a file.

---

Well, the answer to:

> Is it possible to do simple arithmetic in sed addresses?

rhetorically is, it depends on one's abilities, wishes and desires as well as a realistic assessment of practicality.  As well, the implication is that a single `sed` invocation should be used for this task exclusively.  But yes it is possible.

A firm grounding in the studies of Automata, Formal Languages and Recursive Function Theory does not hurt.

As stated in previous answers: Not only can `sed` do simple arithmetic but also any computable function which includes complex arithmetic.  To do so however requires implementing the Primitive Recursive Functions (PRF) (which of course `sed` does) of Recursive Function Theory (RFT). Of course the finite size of machine architecture does limit the computation without infinite tape resources as a Turing machine proves. In any case not wishing to demonstrate this the precedents are to be found in the `sed` manual.

Specifically, to do arithmetic (finitely) an RPN calculator:
https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Increment-a-number.html#FOOT9

Now then, using such a tool can create a `sed` script that precomputes the arithmetic that is then embedded in a `sed` script to print the desired output. A simple demonstration is given by the OP noting now that the shell arithmetic computation can be done using the RPN `sed` script.

This reduces to a form such as (very crude)

```
sed '/$(sed RPN($= - 3*4) file)/;p;' file
```

but still requires feeding `sed` a `sed`'d script.
Also, there is arguably the quibbling over the use of `bash $()` but it could be argued `bash` is already used to execute the first  'sed' so no harm no foul.

Recognizing that `sed` implements the PRF or equivalently is Turing complete means that yes, a single invocation of `sed` is adequate.

The paradigm can therefore do this.

Some commands that could expedite this task are:

```
e, e command, r, R, w, W
```

in addition to the usual hold and pattern buffer commands.

The `r, R, w, W` commands are particularly advantageous as temporary buffer space.

```
e [command]  [3.7 Commands Specific to GNU sed][2]

This command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into
pattern space. Without parameters, the e command executes the 
command that is found in pattern space ...
```

More abstractly, it is completely possible, though *highly* impractical, to write a `sed` script to execute the `sed` paradigm itself that also includes arithmetic calculations even in addresses.

---

A `sed` peculiarity. The expression `/\n/` will not match any address and matches in pattern space only if a `sed` command like 'N'ext or s/.*/\n/ introduces one.
Confirmed via:

```
echo -e '\n\n'  | sed -n '   /\n/    {s//hello/;p}'
```

*But*

```
echo -e '\n\n'  | sed -n '0,/\n\n\n/ {s//hello/;p}'
```

outputs ***3*** blank lines and

```
echo -e '\n\n'  | sed -n '0,/\n/     {s/.*/hello/;p}'
echo -e '\n\n'  | sed -n '0,/\n\n\n/ {s/.*/hello/;p}'
```

each output ***3*** hello's

```
hello
hello
hello
```

while **this is** well-behaved:

```
echo -e '\n\n'  | sed -n '0,/^$/     {s//hello/;p}'
```

---

Comment: That does **not** address the question of arithmetic in addresses; you're doing that "by hand" in doing the same op 4 times.

Comment: thinking inside outside the box using nothing but sed and since it must be entered in bash then |'ng is inclusive

Comment: - indeed arguable  - However  the OP did ask: But maybe there is a workaround? - for sed add/subtract arithmetic see http://rosettacode.org/wiki/A%2BB#sed and then use sed to edit a sed script to do the task